# How to connect OpenTelemetry Java agent to Azure Application Insights backend?

Tags: java, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry

In my Java application I loaded the [OpenTelemetry Java instrumentation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation) jar as a Java agent. This will automatically collect all kinds of data from third party libraries that my application uses such as Jetty and Logback, without me needing to change any code.

By default this library will try to sent that to a Collector running on the same machine at a certain port. However I want the data to go into Azure Application Insights. Which is not one of the [default exporters](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/configuration/#exporters) that are supported.

There are [exporters for Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/telemetry-application-insights?pivots=programming-language-java). However I don't understand how I can hook these up and if that is possible at all without any code changes in Java. I get the impression that those exporters do not work together with the Java agent library that automatically collects all kind of data? The examples in the documentation seem to assume that you are not using the java agent but want to manually add instrumentation to your code, which is not what I want.

Note that I am aware the MS also provides there own Java agent the collects data and sends that into Application Insights. I have used that and that works fine but I want to use the OpenTelemetry one.

Comment: in DAPR https://docs.dapr.io/operations/monitoring/tracing/open-telemetry-collector-appinsights/ they decided to consume tracings as Zipkin and convert them - using side car - to App Insight. I am going to copy such idea because I also can't find any simple fire-and-forgot solution to integrate OpenTelemetry with AppInsights

Comment: Thanks for that info. I got it somewhat working now using the opentelemetry-collector-contrib container which contains the azuremonitorexporter see the github readme https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/azuremonitorexporter. But it seems that only trace data is support by that exporter not metrics and logs. Have not found a solution yet that also supports log information.